# PHP Get parameter from function name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i want create a function as in laravel eloquent that determinate parameter from the name , for example whereName() whereAdresse() .

how can i make this , thank you

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Comment: show us your efforts please, i mean your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need edit Eloquent magic method __call() like this:

```
public function __call($name, $value)
{
   if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'where') {
      $this->where(substr($name, 5), $value);
      //or try call_user_func([$this, 'where'], array_merge(substr($name, 5), $value));
   } else {
      parent::__call($name, $value);
   }
}
```

I think that you desire is a bad desire =)